# Sorting out tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table that is something like this, my goal is to return a result in order based on the episode number. I have done, ORDER BY episode_number, and it is giving different outcome.

```
id    |     episode_number

1           50
2           52
3           51
4           53-54
5           57-58
6           55-56
```

Desire results:

```
id    |     episode_number

1           50
2           51 
3           52
4           53-54
5           55-56
6           57-58
```

Comment: `order by episode_number` should produce the results that you want for this data.

Comment: Nope, i get 1 10 100 1000 and so on....

Comment: Your `id` column values does not match `episode_number` values in desired results block (comparing to first table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are sorting strings, but you want the sort by numbers.  MySQL has a very nice feature of converting strings to numbers in a numeric context, by using the leading digits.  This should do what you want:

```
order by (episode_number + 0)
```

Comment: This will work fine, but how about episode number with double episode in it that is something like 45-46, or 66-67